# Cannot start Fedora when installed on two disks

Tags: hard-drive, boot, installation, ssd, fedora

My laptop has an SSD and a HDD. There is now no OS on my laptop.

Before I had installed Fedora 18 successfully (it was only on the SSD). Then I made some mistakes and the OS broke. Now I want to reinstall it.

This time I will install / and  swap on SSD and /home on the HDD. When I partitioned the drives  I choose ssd to be bootable. The installation succeeded but I cannot start it. 
It just shows a black screen with a cursor blinking in the top-left corner.

Comment: did you try ctrl+alt+f1 to login in fedora root mode?
the matter is where /boot/grub/grub.conf is located it should be on SSD drive that is marked as boot

Comment: in rescue mode or from liveCD shell `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/newroot/boot /dev/your_ssd_device`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `/boot` on the drive which boots earlier, so make sure it is on the correct drive.

Comment: Yeah, you answer is right. This kind of laptop has a ssd and hdd. But they act as a large ssd. And by default it boots from the hdd and can only boot from it. So I have to put /boot on the hdd or put the whole system on the ssd.